# Is TQBF problem where clauses are in 3-CNF format PSPACE-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

TQBF is a canonically **PSPACE**-complete problem. It consists of boolean formula such that all its variables are quantified. The question is whether a given TQBF instance is TRUE or FALSE.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula

My query is regarding the formula part. No source explicitly mentions that the formula is in CNF or 3-CNF format. Since 3-CNF is **NP**-complete, the 3-CNF version of TQBF should be **PSPACE**-complete. But can someone please point to a source that mentions it explicitly?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327915/is-3-qbf-defined-similarly-to-3-sat-is-pspace-complete

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi Thank you. I think it does but a doubt: " Tseytin transformation, which allows the efficient transformation of any Boolean formula to CNF. The use of extension variables prevents the exponential blowup of terms while keeping the resulting formula equisatisfiable, though not completely equivalent." Can you please elaborate this technicality?  I am unclear about this: "....the resulting formula equisatisfiable, though not completely equivalent" part. what does that imply?